# Dropdownlist returns Undefined in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu

I would like to get the list of Stocks in a dropdownlist based on the selected value of Category dropdown list but I am getting "undefined" in the Stock dropdown list options. This is the code i used:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<Category> categories = _dbcontext.Category.ToList();
    ViewBag.ListCategories = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");            
    return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetStockByCat(int CatId)
{
    List<Stock> stocks = new List<Stock>();
    stocks = _dbcontext.Stock.Where(s => s.CategoryId == CatId).ToList();
    SelectList stocksList = new SelectList(stocks, "StockId", "Name");
    return Json(stocksList);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.ListCategories, null, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "GetStocks(this.value)" })
<select id="stocks" name="stocks" class="form-control"></select>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetStocks(_catId) {
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#stocks").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetStockByCat", "Stock")';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { CatId: _catId },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>---------</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += '<option value="' + data[x].Value + '">' + data[x].Text + '</option>';
            }
            $("#stocks").html(markup).show();
            
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });

}
```

I am getting "undefined" in the Stock dropdown list options with the correct number of stock, for example if categorie1 has 5 stocks the dropdownlist is populated with 5 "undefined". I googled a lot and tried many solutions but still getting this "undefined". Any suggestions??

Comment: How you are getting `ViewBag.ListCategories` could you please  share that as well?

Comment: SelectList class does not contains property Value or Text that is why you are getting undefined.
Try console.log(data) 
you will understand the properties of SelectList or refer the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting "undefined" in the Stock dropdown list options with the
> correct number of stock, for example if categorie1 has 5 stocks the
> dropdownlist is populated with 5 "undefined".

Actually, the reason you are getting "undefined" is pretty obvious because you are getting your GetStockByCat controller response as `text` and `value` pairs which you can see below:

[image]

However, within your for loop you are binding data as Text and Value which is not matching what you are getting. I have reproduced your issue which you can see below:

[image]

**Solution:**

Instead of this:

```
 markup += '<option value="' + data[x].Value + '">' + data[x].Text + '</option>';
```

Modify This:

```
markup += '<option value="' + data[x].value + '">' + data[x].text + '</option>';
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:**  Incorrect Key and Value causing your "undefined" value in dropdown which can be replaced as data[x].value  and  data[x].text